# How to encrypt LVM partition with LUKS after installation?

Tags: lvm, encryption, luks

Is it possible to encrypt a LMV partition after having installed an OS?

I just finally managed to get LVM but I couldn't figure out how to get it encrypted. The installer didn't seem to provide for that to happen.

To be more specific, I installed Lubuntu 18.10 which utilizes the Calamares installer.

I've installed Lubuntu successfully but it's not encrypted.

Is it possible to use LUKS to do something at this point or is there an alternative?

EDIT:
I am aiming for FDE. I want all partitions encrypted (/, home, swap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ThatRandomGuy,

You have already done with installation so / file encryption is not possible.

During installation you need to tick the check box "Encrypt the new Lubuntu installation for security" as shown in below figure.

[image: Page to choose system level encryption]

In case if you need to to encrypt home it possible by following below article.

[Creating Encrypted filesystem in RedHat Enterprise Linux 7 and Variants](https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/creating-encrypted-filesystem-in-redhat-enterprise-linux-7-and-variants/)

The guide is for RHEL based operating system but steps are exactly similar and still this works for Ubuntu based operating system as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable encryption of your home folder you will need to install and use these packages: [`ecryptfs-utils`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ecryptfs-utils/) and [`cryptsetup`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cryptsetup/). Also you will need another user account with administrator (sudo) privileges. The full documentation is here:

How to Encrypt Your Home Folder After Installing Ubuntu
If you want to enable full disk encryption after installation, the short answer for now is probably: no, you can't. Anyway, if you are interested about this, your question is duplicate of:

- [Is there a way to do full disk encryption after the install?](https://askubuntu.com/q/96870/147044)
- [Full disk encryption](https://askubuntu.com/q/230213/147044)

Comment: I used this answer initially but found that this cannot encrypt root. It simply encrypts my home and swap. Recognizing the resources you gave, I'm going to assume the answer to my question is no. What bothers me is that calamares won't let me create LVM or LUKS during the install. It assumes I already have a minimal LVM setup. I don't know how to create a LUKS partition pre-install.